# Cannot draw a proper circle with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I cannot draw a proper circle, no matter what. I'm always getting an ellipse. Here's example code to show you what I mean:

```js
function canvasClicked(number) {
  var c = "canvas" + number;
  var canvas = document.getElementById(c);
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var centerX = 150;
  var centerY = 75;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, 70, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.strokeStyle = "red";
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
#canvas1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" onclick="canvasClicked(1)"></canvas>
```

I tried to identify the cause of the issue but without any success. I know that the centerX and centerY should be equal to element.width / 2 and element.height / 2 but that gives me even more awkward results, moving the ellipse away from the center of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
#canvas1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

while using this:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" onclick="canvasClicked(1)"></canvas>
```

or to be more exact: The visible css dimensions are not the same as the underlying canvas dimensions. Because not setting them as attributes on the element:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" onclick="canvasClicked(1)" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

will result in the canvas using the default values 300x150px.

demo: http://jsbin.com/geralevi/1/

---

further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage

> **Note**: If your renderings seem distorted, try specifying your width and
>   height attributes explicitly in the  attributes, and not using
>   CSS.